# SetTimeout not correctly set in angular

Tags: angular

I am having angular 8 application and see an implementation of setTimeout to measure the time of inactivity of the website. 
I am trying to understand the actual value set for the timeout. The environment.userIdleMinutes is set to 5. I can also see that it is multiplied by 60 and 1000. 
I am still not clear why its multiplied by 60 * 1000. Could somebody explain

```
 this.timerHandle = setTimeout(() => this.logout(), environment.userIdleMinutes * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: var that = this; // no need of this line
this.messageSuccess = true;

setTimeout(()=>{    //<<<---    using ()=> syntax
      this.messageSuccess = false;
 }, 3000);

Comment: A minute has 60 seconds and a second has 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: It is converting `minutes` to `milliseconds`. as `setTimeout`'s 2nd property accepts time in `milliseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

it is trying to convert it into milliseconds format.

It is first multiplying it to 60 to convert it to seconds then with 1000 to convert it to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of `setTimeout()` is the time in `milliseconds`.
You have `userIdleMinutes` in minute and you have to convert it to `millisecond`.

Here, `environment.userIdleMinutes = n minute = n*60 second = n*60*1000` `millisecond`.